# Trouble with .htacess redirection

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, redirects, url, 301-redirect

I use this redirect rule to redirect users from `www.domain.com/admin` to `www.domain.com/wp-admin` on a WordPress site.

```
RedirectMatch 301 \@admin http://www.domain.com/wp-admin
```

The problem is that instead redirecting to `wp-admin/`, it redirects to an article called *Administrators are awesome people* (slug : `administrators-are-awesome-people`)

I can guess what is going on, WP sees that there is an article slug starting with "admin", and redirects to it, overruling my own rule.

Is there a way to be more specific, like saying "redirect urls that end with exactly `admin` ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the ["Redirection" wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) - Certainly saves time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 RewriteRule ^admin?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/wp-admin\/" [R=301,L]
```